# Make base class pointer behave like derived class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers

If I create a pointer out of my Shape base class, how would I got about making it behave like the circle (derived) class? Here are my class definitions:

```
    //CShape.h class definition
    //Shape class definition
    #ifndef CSHAPE_H
    #define CSHAPE_H

    class CShape
    {
    protected:
        float area;
        virtual void calcArea();
    public:
        float getArea()
        {
            return area;
        }
    };


    class CCircle : public CShape
    {
    protected:
        int centerX;
        int centerY;
        float radius;
        void calcArea()
        {
            area = float(M_PI * (radius * radius));
        }
    public:
        CCircle(int pCenterX, int pCenterY, float pRadius)
        {
            centerX = pCenterX;
            centerY = pCenterY;
            radius = pRadius;
        }
        float getRadius()
        {
            return radius;
        }
    };
```

In my project file where I'm calling these objects, I have the following code:

```
            CShape *basePtr = new CCircle(1, 2, 3.3);
            basePtr->getRadius();
```

It seems to me like this should work, however I'm told CShape has no member "getRadius()."

EDIT
Based on the response below I tried to dynamic_cast the basePtr object to CCircle like so:

```
CCircle *circle = new CCircle(1, 2, 3.3);
basePtr = dynamic_cast<CCircle *>(circle);
```

This failed too, however. I've never done a dynamic_cast and am unfamiliar with most of the syntax in C++, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would it work? You just wrote that `CShape` has no such member.

Comment: I thought a base class pointer could point to a derived class object? I guess I should be saying that I think this part should work: CShape *basePtr = new CCircle(1, 2, 3.3);

Comment: Well, it does. But that doesn't affect the validity of the other statement.

Comment: How would I write the syntax of a dynamic_cast? I tried to simply cast the object like this: (CCircle)basePtr->getRadius() but that didn't work either...

Comment: Do the `dynamic_cast` just vice versa, cast from `CShape*` to `CCircle*` whenever you need to handle specifics of your `CCircle` class. The `dynamic_cast<CCircle*>(basePtr)` will return a null pointer if `basePtr` doesn't point to a `CCircle` instance.

Comment: you can do casts, but that's probably the wrong way to solve the problem. could you tell us why you want to call `getRadius` on a generic `CShape` which doesn't support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get to `getRadius` function you must declare it of type `CCircle`:

```
        CCircle *basePtr = new CCircle(1, 2, 3.3);
        basePtr->getRadius();
```

Otherwise, if you want to declare `basePtr` as `CShape`, use dynamic binding with `dynamic_cast` or use c-style cast directly, as @Janisz pointed out.

```
       CShape *basePtr = new CCircle(1, 2, 3.3);
       CCircle *child
       // choose one of the two ways, either this:
       child = (CCircle*)basePtr; // C-style cast
       // or this:
       child = dynamic_cast<CCircle*>(basePtr); // C++ version
       child->getRadius();
```

Comment: Or add casting `(CCircle)basePtr->getRadius();`

Comment: This worked perfectly. This is maybe my 3rd or 4th time coding in C++ so thank you very much!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath why do you think so?

Comment: This remedies the symptoms, but not the cause. It might be a problematic advice to give to somebody who is starting to learn C++.

Comment: @bitmask Please feel free to edit the post if you think some point is missing

Comment: @Desolator: See my answer. I don't think your post can be edited to reflect that issue. Frankly, it's quite dangerous to recommend something like "just cast it, and it'll 'work'" without explaining what the real issue is with the OP. But I hesitate to DV because you're technically correct.

Answer (score 4):

You might be careful with casts. First of all `dynamic_cast`s add a runtime overhead for checking the type of your pointer (see *rtti*). `static_cast`s are a lot cheaper but do not check the dynamic type of the object.

Downcasts are indicators that there *might* (!) be something wrong in your design. By no means is this always the case, but especially if you are learning C++ OOP try to avoid them.

Since it is not meaningful to add a `getRadius` to `CShape` (simply because not all shapes have a radius), a function that deals with a `CShape*` shouldn't rely on the object being a `CCircle`.

For example, you could be trying to determine the area of your shape. That's probably a meaningful thing for all shapes, so you would add a `virtual` abstract function that computes the area for a shape. Your circle then would implement this by using it's radius, a rectangle by using the product of its side lengths and so forth.

---

Edit: To understand why

```
CShape *basePtr = new CCircle(1, 2, 3.3);
basePtr->getRadius();
```

cannot work, you have to understand that C++ is strongly typed. In the second line, you are trying to access a member called `getRadius` from `CShape`. That class (nor any of its parent classes) has no such a member. It is true that (while your program runs) the variable `basePtr` points to an object of type `CCircle`, but that cannot be known at compile time (in the general case, that is). Thus, C++ doesn't even bother to check derived types, because (again, in general) it simply cannot. When compiling this line, it might not even *know* all derived types, so it has no chance to understand what you meant to do.

As far as the compiler is concerned, `basePtr` could be pointing at an object that is of a type that does *not* have a `getRadius` member.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a static cast ( http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ ) from CShape to Circle

Alternatively, you could declare getRadius() as an virtual function in CShape, which you may not want to do given the name of the class.